# How to properly set the accesstoken and the refreshtoken when the accesstoken expires?

Tags: integration, servicem8

I have two webhooks setup that should listen to job created in servicem8. Based on this the information should be transfered to the airtable base. My airtable part is working. I am not able to fire the webhook from my endpoint. IS there a way to check if my webhook is receiving any data. Also the webhook was working fine before 2 days and suddenly stopped and doesn't seems to work anymore. I am not sure if it is a code issue or a servicem8 issue.

I am trying to fire my webhook when the job status changes to complete. It should then output the data into my airtable base.